# How can I modify the color of font and using independent backgrounds with the following template?

Tags: beamer, graphics, sharelatex

Hello I am working using Sharelatex to use latex online it comes with several templates to create presentations, I decided to use one called: Radboud University Beamer, below I put the complete code of the main two parts, example.tex and ru.sty.

I would like to change the color of the font so analyzing the code I found the following part in ru.sty,

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)}
```

Where I believe that is defining the color of the font, however it is a little advance the code for me and I was not able to change the color of the font,  I would like to know how to change it, I would like to know if it is possible or if the color of the letter belong to the theme,

The second issue it is about the background that is defined at the following part of ru.sty:

```
% Background
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bg}{ru_background}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{bg}}
```

In this part you can select one image, the problem is that if I select some one then all the pages have the same background I would like to have independent backgrounds, thanks a lot of the support and all of the recommendations are welcome to understand how does this template works, below I put the complete code of the two main parts that shape the template.

First Part called: example.tex

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx,hyperref,ru,url}

% The title of the presentation:
%  - first a short version which is visible at the bottom of each slide;
%  - second the full title shown on the title slide;
\title[RU style for Beamer]{
  Radboud University style for Beamer \LaTeX}

% Optional: a subtitle to be dispalyed on the title slide
\subtitle{Show where you're from}

% The author(s) of the presentation:
%  - again first a short version to be displayed at the bottom;
%  - next the full list of authors, which may include contact information;
\author[Pim Vullers MSc]{
  Pim Vullers MSc \\\medskip
  {\small \url{p.vullers@cs.ru.nl}} \\ 
  {\small \url{http://www.cs.ru.nl/~pim/}}}

% The institute:
%  - to start the name of the university as displayed on the top of each slide
%    this can be adjusted such that you can also create a Dutch version
%  - next the institute information as displayed on the title slide
\institute[Radboud University Nijmegen]{
  Institute for Computing and Information Sciences -- Digital Security \\
  Radboud University Nijmegen}

% Add a date and possibly the name of the event to the slides
%  - again first a short version to be shown at the bottom of each slide
%  - second the full date and event name for the title slide
\date[slides Example 2010]{
  the 1st example presentation 2010 \\
  7th October 2010}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}

  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

% Section titles are shown in at the top of the slides with the current section 
% highlighted. Note that the number of sections determines the size of the top 
% bar, and hence the university name and logo. If you do not add any sections 
% they will not be visible.
\section{Introduction}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Introduction}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item This is just a short example
    \item The comments in the \LaTeX\ file are most important
    \item This is just the result after running pdflatex
    \item The style is based on the webpage \url{http://www.ru.nl/}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\section{Background information}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Background information}

  \begin{block}{Slides with \LaTeX}
    Beamer offers a lot of functions to create nice slides using \LaTeX.
  \end{block}

  \begin{block}{The basis}
    This style uses the following default styles:
    \begin{itemize}
      \item split
      \item whale
      \item rounded
      \item orchid
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\section{The important things}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{The important things}

  \begin{enumerate}
    \item This just shows the effect of the style
    \item It is not a Beamer tutorial
    \item Read the Beamer manual for more help
    \item Contact me only concerning the style file
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Analysis of the work}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Analysis of the work}

  This style file gives your slides some nice Radboud branding.
  When you know how to work with the Beamer package it is easy to use.
  Just add:\\ ~~~$\backslash$usepackage$\{$ru$\}$ \\ at the top of your file.
\end{frame}

\section{Conclusion}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Conclusion}

  \begin{itemize}
    \item Easy to use
    \item Good results
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Second part called ru.sty

```
% Copyright 2009 by Pim Vullers
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.



%%%
%%% Inherit definitions from existing themes (DO NOT MODIFY THESE)
%%%

% Layout scheme for outer elements: split header and footer
\useoutertheme{split}

% Color scheme for outer elements: use background colors
\usecolortheme{whale}

% Layout scheme for inner elements: rounded elements
\useinnertheme{rounded} 

% Color scheme for inner elements: use foreground colors
\usecolortheme{orchid}


%%%
%%% Tweak definitions of inner theme to match personal preferences (MODIFY THESE)
%%%

% Itemize items: default (triangle), circle, square, ball
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[circle]

% Enumerate items: default, circle, square, ball
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[circle]

% Outline: default, sections numbered, subsections numbered, circle, square, ball, ball unnumbered
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[default]

% General blocks: 
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded]

% Title page:
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]

% Part page:
\setbeamertemplate{part page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true]

% Navigation symbols:
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}


%%%
%%% Tweak definitions of outer theme to match Radboud (website) style
%%%

% Background
\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bg}{ru_background}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{bg}}

% Colors
\usecolortheme[RGB={190,49,26}]{structure}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{parent=subsection in head/foot}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle right}{parent=section in head/foot}


\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading[frametitle.bg,frametitle right.bg]{beamer@frametitleshade}{\paperheight}{%
  color(0pt)=(frametitle.bg);
  color(\paperwidth)=(frametitle right.bg)}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@topshade}{\paperwidth}{%
    color(0pt)=(bg);
    color(4pt)=(black!50!bg)}
}

% Footline: AUTHOR | TITLE | DATE FRAMENUMBER

\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.25\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortdate
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.416667\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
   \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=0.083333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{title in head/foot}%
    \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{ru theme}{%
  \leavevmode%
  \@tempdimb=2.4375ex%
    \multiply\@tempdimb by\beamer@sectionmax%
  \pgfdeclareimage[height=.9\@tempdimb]{logo}{ru_logo}%
  \logo{\pgfuseimage{logo}}%
  \ifdim\@tempdimb>0pt%
    \advance\@tempdimb by 1.125ex%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb]{section in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertsectionnavigation{.5\paperwidth}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.4\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,right]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\vfil\textbf{\footnotesize\insertshortinstitute~~}\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\@tempdimb,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
      \vbox to\@tempdimb{\vfil\insertlogo\vfil\vfil}%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \fi%
}

\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{ru theme}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  %\vskip-2pt%
  \hbox{\leavevmode
    \advance\beamer@leftmargin by -12bp%
    \advance\beamer@rightmargin by -12bp%
    \beamer@tempdim=\textwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@leftmargin%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by \beamer@rightmargin%
    \hskip-\Gm@lmargin\hbox{%
      \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\begin{minipage}[b]{\paperwidth}%
          \vbox{}\vskip-.75ex%
          \leftskip0.3cm%
          \rightskip0.3cm plus1fil\leavevmode
          \insertframetitle%
          \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
            \strut\par%
          \else
            \par{\usebeamerfont*{framesubtitle}{\usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}\insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
          \fi%
          \nointerlineskip
          \vbox{}%
          \end{minipage}}%
      \beamer@tempdim=\ht\beamer@tempbox%
      \advance\beamer@tempdim by 2pt%
      \begin{pgfpicture}{0.1mm}{0pt}{1.01\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}
        \usebeamercolor{frametitle right}
        \pgfpathrectangle{\pgfpointorigin}{\pgfpoint{\paperwidth}{\beamer@tempdim}}
        \pgfusepath{clip}
        \pgftext[left,base]{\pgfuseshading{beamer@frametitleshade}}
      \end{pgfpicture}
      \hskip-\paperwidth%
      \box\beamer@tempbox%
    }%
    \hskip-\Gm@rmargin%
  }%
%  \nointerlineskip
%    \vskip-0.2pt
%    \hbox to\textwidth{\hskip-\Gm@lmargin\pgfuseshading{beamer@topshade}\hskip-\Gm@rmargin}
%    \vskip-2pt
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- To change the text colour, you can simply use

  ```
  \setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}
  ```
- To have different background images, you can just overwrite the `\pgfdeclareimage` during the presentation.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=red}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bg}{example-image}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\pgfuseimage{bg}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
text
\end{frame}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{bg}{example-image-b}

\begin{frame}
another image
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the support, I was finally able to use this template as I wanted, this was very helpful.